# Run Crontab C++ Script Raspi fail,

Tags: c++, linux, bash, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to make my script that runs every 5 minutes.

> */5 * * * * /home/pi/script.sh

My script contains a C++ program for capturing video for 5 seconds, then saving it to folder and sending it to server with `ncftp`:

> #!/usr/bin/bash/env hbcxx #!/usr/bin/bash
>   ./ca1
>   ncftpput -R -v -u "user" -p "password" 192.168.0.119 /folder/ video/

My video recording program is:

```
string intToString(int number){

    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << number;
    return ss.str();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    string nama_directory= "video";
    int status_D = system("mkdir video" );

    bool recording = false;
    bool startNewRecording = true;

    int inc = 0;
    int i = 0;

    bool firstRun = true;
    bool still = true;

    VideoCapture cap(0); // open the video camera no. 0
    VideoWriter oVideoWriter;//create videoWriter object, not initialized yet
    // if not success, exit program
    if (!cap.isOpened()){

        cout << "ERROR: Cannot open the video file" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    namedWindow("MyVideo",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); //create a window called "MyVideo"

    double dWidth = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH); //get the width of frames of the video
    double dHeight = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT); //get the height of frames of the video

    cout << "Frame Size = " << dWidth << "x" << dHeight << endl;

    //set framesize for use with videoWriter
    Size frameSize(static_cast<int>(dWidth), static_cast<int>(dHeight));

    //clock_t start = clock(), diff;
    while (inc<6){
        int fps = 0;

        while (still) {

           if(startNewRecording){
               //initialize the VideoWriter object
               oVideoWriter  = VideoWriter("/home/pi/video/" + 
                               intToString(inc) +
                               ".avi", 
                               CV_FOURCC('D', 'I', 'V', 'X'),
                               5, frameSize, true); 
               recording = true;
               startNewRecording = false;

               cout<<"New video file created MyVideo"+intToString(inc)+".avi "<<endl;

               //if not initialize the VideoWriter successfully, exit the program
               if ( !oVideoWriter.isOpened() ) {
                   cout << "ERROR: Failed to initialize video writing" << endl;                  getchar();
                  return -1;
               }

           }

           Mat frame;

           bool bSuccess = cap.read(frame); // read a new frame from video

           //if not success, break loop
           if (!bSuccess) {
                cout << "ERROR: Cannot read a frame from video file" << endl;
                break;
           }

           //if we're in recording mode, write to file
           if(recording){
               oVideoWriter.write(frame);
               fps++;
               //show "REC" in top left corner in red
               //be sure to do this AFTER you write to the file so that "REC" doesn't show up
               //on the recorded video.
               putText(frame,"REC",Point(0,60),2,2,Scalar(0,0,255),2);
           }

           imshow("MyVideo", frame); //show the frame in "MyVideo" window
           if(fps>50){
                still=false;
           }


       } // end of second while
       still = true;  
       startNewRecording = true; 
       inc++;
   } // end of first while
return 0;
}
```

The problem is `cron` just makes directory, but isn't making any file `avi`.

### Question:

What am I doing wrong?

Note: if  run just the script it work.

P.S.: Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Try looking at the output of the program to see what went wrong: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/343

A simpler way to log the output would be to write `*/5 * * * * /home/pi/script.sh >> /home/pi/stdout 2>> /home/pi/stderr`. The output of the program will show up in those two files.

Comment: i have solved this problem, for program you must add display setiing in crontab -e,, for ncftp add the source profile in crontab -e